# Is it possible to persist the Class of an object?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have created an Entity class and one of the fields I'd like to be the *Class* of an object i.e. I do not wish to (and *cannot*) persist a concrete object in this field. For example I create and abstract class and it's the *class* of all it's descendants I would like to persist:

```
public abstract class RootType implements Serializable {
private String name;
private Date date;

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public Date getDate(){
    return date;
}
}
```

And two descendants of `RootType`:

```
public class FloatData extends RootType {
Float data;

public void setData(Float data){
    this.data = data;
}

public Float getData(){
    return data;
}
}

public class StringData extends RootType {
String data;

public void setData(String data){
    this.data = data;
}

public String getData(){
    return data;
}
}
```

And the actual Entity class which has a reference to `RootType` or one of its descendants:

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private Class c;

// standard methods omitted for clarity
public void setC(Class c){
    this.c = c;
}

public Class getC(){
    return c;
}
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is this a valid way of achieving this?
2. If valid, does it place minimal data into the data base concerning the Class i.e. just some sort of reference to it?
3. Is there a way to restrict the Class to being of type `RootType.class` or would *every* Customer entity's c field be `RootType.class` even if it was actually a descendant?

I could use an Enum type however that immediately limits me to stating at compile time what `.class` I can have and I would rather avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Yes, that is valid, although you would need to annotate your `c` field with [@Lob](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html)

2.Well, I doubt that only minimal data is persisted, but you can check that yourself. Besides, the biggest problem would be that if you will persist such a class and then later change your class and redeploy, you will get some deserealization problems. This is why I recommend you to save the `Class.getSimpleName()` of the class.

3.If I understand correctly the question: yes, by doing this:

```
public void setC(Class<? extends RootType> c) {
    this.c = c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you change it to a `String` :

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
...
   private String c;
...
}
```

To store it you would do :

```
customer.setC(clazz.getName());
```

and to get it back as a `Class` you would do:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(customer.getC());
```

Comment: Nice. That's another way indeed. Which is more efficient, storing the class as a String or the .class? I am only wondering as I don't want to fill up a database with unnecessary data as I just need some sort of reference to the type of an Object.

Comment: I don't know how the .class will be stored, but it will inevitably be more complex than the string version as it will necessarily contain it.

Comment: Storing the class as a string is better than the binary class as when reflection is used to instantiate it, you will get the current version. This allows you to fix bugs in the class without having to edit your database. Of course this can be a two edged sword if someone removes a property your depending on.

Comment: The String method is very tidy indeed but I was just pondering whether if I store the .class then ALL of the binary data for the Class is saved. Could this be a way of reconstructing a class without an actual .class file? With the String method I need the .class file. Both methods are valid but each have their own uses perhaps?

Comment: KayKay, your answer is excellent as is Andrei's so much so it's hard for me to choose between the two of you and mark as correct so I flipped a coin but I'm afraid Andrei won the flip but many thanks for your help.